# Problema no cordova build

Tags: apache-cordova

Estou tentando rodar o cordova build, porém está apresentando o erro abaixo. 
por favor peço ajuda.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem o Android SDK instalado no seu computador? Já instalou a plataforma Android nesse projeto do Cordova?

Answer (score 1):

1. Verifique se o ficheiro build.bat está realmente no directório **C:\teste\platforms\android\cordova**;
2. Se sim: tente eliminar a plataforma fazendo cordova **platform rm android** na Consola, adicione de seguida novamente com cordova **platform add android** e volte a tentar fazer build.
3. Se não: desinstale o SDK e volte a instalar novamente.